# What's the microseconds precision in PHP under different OSes?

Tags: php, operating-system, precision, microtime

If I do:

```
echo microtime(true);
```

I get the following results:

- On my local Windows development environment I get a 4 digit precision (1310564569.4162 for example).
- On my live CentOS (Linux) server I get a 2 digit precision (1310564569.41 for example).

OK so depending on the platform your running you get different precisions? Or this is a PHP/OS configuration?

Also from the [microtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) PHP docs:

> This function is only available on operating systems that support the
> gettimeofday() system call.

Which OSes (or conditions/configurations) don't support this?

Answer (score 2):

> If you pass true to microtime() as its only parameter, PHP will return
>   the time in a more obvious format - seconds.microseconds, like this:
>   1174676587.5996
>
> When using microtime(), keep in mind that the return value is a
>   floating-point number. There is a setting in your php.ini file called
>   "precision", which sets the number of significant digits to show in
>   floating-point numbers - note that is significant digits, not decimal
>   places, which means your return value from microtime() may not be as
>   precise as you want. Above, for example, you can see we only have four
>   decimal places returned - this is because php.ini defaults precision
>   to 14, and there are ten digits before the decimal place.
>
> If you increase the value of precision up to, say, 18, and run
>   microtime() again, you will get results that are more accurate:
>   1174677004.8997819.

by [tuxradar.com](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/5/1)